# Android- Can i have a FAB on top of webview?

Tags: android

Can I have a FAB on top of WebView in Android ? I should able to call one on click method using the FAB button itself.

Comment: yes, you can. Create a RelativeLayout and put FAB with webview inside RelativeLayout

Answer (score 5):

Here is you solution :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your webview inside relative layout, and add FAB below webview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/webView" />

<!-- your FAB goes here -->
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Yeah ...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.fab.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android Floating Action Button" />
//create web view layout here
</RelativeLayout>
```